# visualg escada quebra de linha

Tags: portugol, visualg, quebras-de-linha

Estou com problema no código para fazer a quebra de linha.
Preciso criar uma escada que fique como abaixo:

```
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####
```

Se eu colocar escreval("#") ele quebra a linha, porem o resultado final fica assim:

```
     #
    #
#
   #
#
#
  #
#
#
#
 #
#
#
#
#
```

Alguém sabe qual ajuste devo realizar ?
com o código atual o resultado está ficando dessa maneira:

```
Quantidade de degraus: 5
     #    ##   ###  #### #####

Algoritmo "escada"
Var
p, x1, x, lin, col, degr: inteiro

Inicio
Escreva ("Quantidade de degraus: ")
Leia (degr)
x:=degr
x1:=1
Para lin de 1 ate degr passo 1 faca
Para col de 1 ate x passo 1 faca
escreva(" ")
Fimpara
x:=x-1
Para p de 1 ate x1 passo 1 faca
escreva("#")
Fimpara
x1:=x1+1
escreva( )
Fimpara
fimalgoritmo
```

desde já muito obrigado !!

Comment: Não entendi a variável x ai. Estou novo em Lógica de Programação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ficou assim:

```
Algoritmo "escada"
   Var
   p, x1, x, lin, col, degr: inteiro
   Inicio
   Escreva ("Quantidade de degraus: ")
   Leia (degr)
   degr:=degr + 1

   Para lin de degr ate 0 passo -1 faca
        Para col de 1 ate (degr - x) passo 1 faca
             escreva(" ")
        Fimpara
        Para col de 1 ate x passo 1 faca
             escreva("#")
        Fimpara
        x:=degr - lin
        escreval("")
   Fimpara
fimalgoritmo
```

Qualquer dúvida é só comentar aqui que eu respondo. :)

Comment: Muito obrigado !!!
Funcionou perfeitamente aqui!

Comment: a reposta está exata amigo , só queria entender como funciona as variaveis oque cada uma representa a quebra de linha ...

Comment: Leio a variável `degr`, acrescento 1 nela, pois minha estrutura de repetição dai de `degr` até 0, ao colocar +1 certifico que vai realmente até o número desejado. A variável `lin` é um contador, ela vai começar de `degr` e vai ate o 0, uso ela para imprimir cada linha. Na estrutura de repetição interna uso uma variável `col` que vai de 1 até `degr - x` onde `x` é `degr - lin` pois a cada linha vou exibir um espaço ( ) a menos.